# Run Azure WebJob on premises server

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

The application I'm working on has to be deployable on Azure and on a Windows Server.

I'm using a Continuous Azure WebJob, that has some methods with a `[TimerTrigger]` attribute, that work fine on Azure. But I would like them to trigger also when deployed on premises.

Is this something supported? What would be a recommended way to have the exe with the Azure WebJob SDK running on a Windows Server continuously from a DevOps perspective?

I'm using .NET Core 3 and the Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs 3.0 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider the web job project as a console project, and just click the your_webjob.exe to run it continuously(by specifying TimerTrigger). And you can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) to create a .NET core webjob.

Here is an example:

1.Create a .NET core 3.0 console project, and install the following nuget packages:

[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions, version 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions/3.0.0)

[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, version 3.0.10](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/3.0.10)

[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console, version 3.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/3.0.0)

2.Here is the code in program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new HostBuilder();
            builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {

                b.AddTimers();
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddAzureStorage();
            });
            builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();
            });

            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                host.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3.Add appsettings.json file to the project, and then right click the appsettings.json file -> select properties -> set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer". Here is the appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

4. Add a Functions.cs to the project. And here is the code in Functions.cs:

   ```
   using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

   namespace ConsoleApp2
   {
       public class Functions
       {
           public static void CronJob([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer, ILogger logger)
           {
               logger.LogInformation("this is a test message!");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

5.Build the project, then go to the folder where your_webjob.exe is located, just double click the .exe file, it can run continuously on local:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm still wondering what to put in the AzureWebJobsStorage connection. Would it be possible to use something local? I know there is the AzureStorageEmulator, not sure however it is supposed to be used in production.

Comment: @despuestambien, for testing purpose, you can use AzureStorageEmulator, it's local. But for production, you'd better use a real azure storage account connection string.

Comment: @despuestambien, if the post is helpful, please help mark it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However it seems to me that there isn't a good alternative for the WebJob requiring AzureStorage. It would be necessary to connect to the cloud from the on prem server which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @despuestambien, eeem, this is by design for the webjob sdk, we cannot change it. But good luck and share with us if you have any solution:)

Comment: @IvanYang do you know any reasons why this could be discouraged for, say, a production environment?

Comment: @despuestambien, I wonder if you were able to resolve the Azure Storage issue.  If you are not actually using the storage as an actual application storage (like a database, for example), emulator could be there just to store the web job "assets".  If your application is using something like SQL Server for any actual workloads, then just ignore the azure storage aspect and have it connect to the emulator like a dummy.
Otherwise, maybe switch to TopShelf https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview/index.html